# How to transmit data from postgres SQL to Microsoft SQL without arriving as "NULL"-values at the Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis

**Background**: I want to transmit data from a postgres SQL server to a Microsoft SQL server via SSIS.

[image: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=d58423-1442932408.png]

**Problem**: The data arrive with “`NULL`”-Values in the Microsoft SQL table even though the format of the source (postgres SQL server) and the format of the destination (Microsoft SQL server) are the same.

**One example**:

Postgres SQL: Column defined as charactervarying(100)

- Test10InSt

Microsoft SQL: nvarchar(100)

- NULL

Does someone know how to solve that problem?

- Is it a special format I need to choose in the “Data transmission” and if so what format exactly?
- Does the problem originate at another place?

Comment: What does your Data Conversion specify?

Comment: Unicode string [DT_WSTR]

Comment: Excellent. If you double click on the line between the Multicast and the Data Conversion and look at the metadata tab, what does is specify for `first_paid_product`

Comment: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=5b162f-1442935650.png

Comment: Data Conversion: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=397e0f-1442935825.png